# rubymotion- formotion & rendering data to appear on tableview

Tags: rubymotion

i have an app thats setup to use formation in one controller and i have another controller thats a uivuewcontroller with a subclass of tableview and i want the information in the form controller to appear on my tableview. i used cdq to store the data also.

heres a example of my code, not sure if if the way I'm trying to do this is correct or not.

```
def init
@form = Formotion::Form.new({
persist_as: :post,
sections: [{
  title: "post",
  rows: [{
    title: "name",
    key: :name,
    placeholder: "example name",
    type: :string,
    input_accessory: :done,
    }
...
{
      rows: [{
      title: "Post",
      type: :submit,
    }]
@form.on_submit do |form|
  process_info(form)
end
super.initWithForm(form)
end


def process_info(form)
  data = form.render
end
```

any example code or steps to make it appear on my other uiviewcontroller with the tableview subclass would be greatly appreciated.

--EDIT--

heres what i added to process info method

```
def process_info
data = form.render
[:name,:example,:example].each { |prop|
PostScreenController.controller.send(prop.to_s + "="  , form.render[prop])
}
self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:lambda{})
end
```

one more thing to add is that the PostScreeController is the controller with the tableview that I'm trying to populate with the formotion data.

and i got this error message in the terminal

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'post_controller.rb:95:in `block in process_info': undefined method `controller' for PostScreenController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: How are you persisting the data captured from the form?

Comment: @willrax can you further explain what you mean by persisting the data? i used cdq to store all the data in the schema that it generated but thats about it. i also am using fetch_controller on my tableview to fetch the data. if that answers your question.

Comment: Ok, cdq is good. Maybe I'm a bit unsure of the question... Are you able to get populate the cells in the tableview with any data that is entered through the form? Or are you looking to update the table once new data has been entered?

Comment: @willrax I'm trying to populate the table with the data that is entered from the formotion controller. but when i click on the submit button nothing happens, i tried a combination of things to see if it would work and most of the time it crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one that I use. Very similar. I just think you're passing some variables around that aren't quite right. Ie: Setting form to an instance variable but then passing a standard variable in to the process_info method. Hope this helps. :)

```
def init
  self.initWithForm(new_form)
end

def new_form
  form = Formotion::Form.new({
    persist_as: :post,
    sections: [{
      title: "post",
      rows: [{
        title: "name",
        key: :name,
        placeholder: "example name",
        type: :string,
        input_accessory: :done,
        },
      # ....
   {
    rows: [{
     title: "Post",
     type: :submit,
    }]]

  form.on_submit do |f|
    process_info
  end

  form
end

def process_info
  data = form.render
end
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, just had a chance to try the code that you gave me. and when i clicked on the submit/post button nothing happen so i added some code into the process_info method to see if the info from the form would send to the other controller and it crashed.ill edit original post and show you

Comment: If you're loading your UITable using the data stored in cdq and you've used all the correct delegate methods you'll just need to call reloadData. That means that in your process_info you'll need to save the data from the form using cdq.